# Install Windows Server Roles/Features using C# 32bit and Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to install Windows Server Roles using c# by executing powershell commands. here is my code:

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "ServerManager" });
Runspace PowerShellRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
PowerShellRunspace.Open();
using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
 powershell.Runspace = PowerShellRunspace;
 powershell.AddCommand("Install-WindowsFeature");
 powershell.AddArgument("XPS-Viewer");
 powershell.Invoke();
 }
 PowerShellRunspace.Close();
```

but i get the error The tearm 'install-windowsfeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function....

Please let me know how to install XPS-Viewer. I am using .NET 2.0 32 bit and executing it on Windows Server 2016 OS.

Comment: What Powershell version do you have? Also, why not .NET 4.5?

Comment: Powershell 5 is install by default on Server 2016 OS. This code needs to be executed on Server 2008 R2 whre .NET 4.5 will not be there.

Comment: On Server 2008 R2 use `Add-WindowsFeature` or use `dism.exe` which works everywhere.

Comment: On Windows Server 2008 R2, the cmdlet's name is old, [`Add-WindowsFeature`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662309.aspx). Try using this in your code.

Comment: ok But how about in Server 2016 OS

Comment: `Install-WindowsFeature` works fine on 2012 R* and 2016, but for 2008 R2 use `Add-WindowsFeature`

Comment: but when i run the above code i get the error The tearm 'install-windowsfeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function....

Comment: If you are doing this multiple times, maybe look at http://boxstarter.org ?